# PHP get the max match word array value from an extensive array

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am trying to create a function to get the max match word array value from an extensive array.
I do not have expertise in PHP. Does witch PHP function do without looping array?

Example

```
$word  = "My New Scooter is very Good":

$array = [
    "Good Scooter"
    "lovely very Good Scooter"
    "Scooter is very Good and New"
    "Scooter is very Good and its My New Scooter"
]
```

4th Number array has All word, so the function should return "Scooter is very Good and its My New Scooter."

The above is just an example, but the array is extensive.

Comment: And what if several items in your array have all the words (or the same number of matching words)?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Then return maximum match word count first value.

Comment: You might be interested in learning about Naive-Bayes classification, you can feed it your array and it will return best match, few libs out there like PHP-ML, also https://github.com/niiknow/bayes which is simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except perhaps in the magical world of *my little poney*, you can't do that without looping.

```
$sentence = 'My New Scooter is very Good';

$array = [
    "Good Scooter",
    "lovely very Good Scooter",
    "Scooter is very Good and New",
    "Scooter is very Good and its My New Scooter"
];

$words = explode(' ', $sentence);

$winner = ['index' => false, 'count' => 0 ];

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $common = array_intersect($words, explode(' ', $v));
    
    if ( $winner['count'] < count($common) )
        $winner = ['index' => $k, 'count' => count($common)];

    if ( $winner['count'] === count($words) )
        break;
}

var_dump($winner);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/HLdDJ)

Feel free to build a function to do that with a `return` instead of a `break`.